# How to set current_user for pytest?

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I'm writing a unit test for a view that uses the current logged in user in a query:

```
@app.route('/vendors/create', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def create_vendors():
    vendor_form = VendorForm(request.form)
    if vendor_form.validate_on_submit():
        vendor = db.session.query(Vendors).filter(Vendors.name == vendor_form.name.data,
                                                  Vendors.users.contains(g.user)).first()
        if vendor:
            flash('There is a vendor with this name already.')
            return redirect(url_for('create_vendors', vendor_form=vendor_form))
        vendor = Vendors(name=vendor_form.name.data, aws_access_key=vendor_form.aws_access_key.data,
                         merchant_key=vendor_form.merchant_key.data, secret_key=vendor_form.secret_key.data)
        vendor.users.append(current_user)
        db.session.add(vendor)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('vendors'))
    return render_template('edit_vendor.html', vendor_form=vendor_form)
```

and the test:

```
def test_create_vendor(self):
    response = TestViews.client.post('/vendors/create', follow_redirects=True,
                                     data=dict(name='Name', aws_access_key='aws_access_key',
                                               merchant_key='merchant_key',
                                               secret_key='secret_key'))
    assert response.status_code == 200
    vendors = db.session.query(Vendors).filter(Vendors.aws_access_key == 'aws_access_key').all()
    assert len(vendors) == 1
    assert vendors[0].name == 'Name'
```

and in my settings `LOGIN_DISABLED = True`.

My problem is that when running the test [current_user](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#flask_login.current_user) is never set.

I've tried logging in using the test client and wrapping my tests in a `with TestLogin.client:` but `current_user` is just never set. Any ideas on how to set it?

Comment: did you call `login_user` (`flask_security.utils`) in your setUp? you can also try with `with self.client:`

Comment: Yeah, none of those work.

Comment: How about `self.client.post(...)` instead of `TestViews.client.post(...)`

Comment: Tried it, no luck.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Consider the below sample app I created for this question

```
from flask import Flask, request,
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_login.utils import login_required, current_user, login_user

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'super secret key'
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)

class MyUser():
    name = "tarun"

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    def is_active(self):
        return True

    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

    def get_id(self):
        return 10


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return MyUser()

@app.route("/login", methods=["POST"])
def login():
    login_user(MyUser())
    return "Authenticated"

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def index():
    return "Authenticated " # + current_user


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

There are different ways to testing logged in flows.

**Disable Login and @login_required**

In this you don't use `current_user` in the request call and just protect the flow to an authenticated user. In such case you can use below kind of approach

```
import flasktest as flaskr

class FlaskrTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        flaskr.app.testing = True
        flaskr.app.config['LOGIN_DISABLED'] = True
        flaskr.app.login_manager.init_app(flaskr.app)
        self.app = flaskr.app.test_client()

    def test_without_login(self):
        res = self.app.post("/")

        assert "Unauthorized" in res.data
```

The test will fail in this case as the user will allows to access a authenticated flow. And the `current_user` will be set as a Anonymous User. And it is as good as disabling `@login_required`.

**Testing with actual login**

To do this you need to make sure that you can login to your app using POST to the endpoint where you actually login

```
import unittest

import flasktest as flaskr

class FlaskrTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        flaskr.app.testing = True
        self.app = flaskr.app.test_client()

    def tearDown(self):
        pass

    def test_login(self):
        self.app.post("/login")

        res = self.app.get("/")

        assert "Authenticated" in res.data

    def test_without_login(self):
        res = self.app.post("/")

        assert "Unauthorized" in res.data
```

This will even set the `current_user` correctly. In my case I didn't take any form data parameters, in your case you will use something like below

```
self.app.post('/login', data=dict(
        username=username,
        password=password
    ), follow_redirects=True)
```

**Using Session Cookies**

In this case you set the session `user_id` and `_fresh`

```
def test_login_session(self):
    with self.app.session_transaction() as sess:
        sess['user_id'] = '12'
        sess['_fresh'] = True  # https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#fresh-logins

    res = self.app.get("/")

    assert "Authenticated" in res.data
```

This will in turn call the

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return MyUser()
```

To get the actual user based on the `user_id` provided by us in session `12`

Comment: Not sure this represents my problem.

Comment: @ruipacheco I think this answer solves your problem, could you please explain why this doesn't solve your question.

Comment: I've tried everything he's shown, still don't have a current_user in my views when I run unit tests. Views that don't depend on current_user work fine.

Comment: @ruipacheco, I have tested every single code before posting, so I am not sure if you are using it right. Possible to share git repo with minimal code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I suspect this may be on my side indeed. I can't share the code unfortunately.

Comment: How have you configured the Login setup? I can give you a working example in similar setup

Answer (score -1):

Simply mock flask_login.current_user and set a fixed return value like 'testuser'

Comment: *Simply mock* is too vague. Would you please share an example of a mock of `current_user`?